# Adding and Removing Django Apps without server restart?

Tags: python, django

Which changes are necessary (if possible in any way) to include/exclude a django app from a django installation without restarting the nginx server?

Especially, I want to add a new (dynamically created) application to the project without interrupting user inputs (file up- and downloads). The project does not need to access the new application, but the new application adds urls, models and databases to the existing project.

Until now I just restarted the server in idle times, but I would like to have something like:

```
GET
/add/<app_name>/

def add(request, app_name):
  INSTALLED_APPS.append(app_name)
  DATABASES["app-" + app_name] = { db_data }
  DATABASE_ROUTERS += ["apps." + app_name + ".router.Router",]
  …
```

Is it possible in any (easy) way? Are there other variables I have to modify?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible, nor is it recommended. You need to restart the back-end server (your upstream server in nginx that is running the django process).

In addition, I am curious what you are doing when  you say "dynamically created application", as this sounds like a solution looking for a problem.

Comment: "dynamically created app" could be an application, which is created after uploading a model specification. Afterwards, the object instances can directly be managed by django's admin interface to ease data management without starting an additional server.

Comment: Looks like you need to create one application; to manage these "models" (which sounds like a job for nosql if the structure is flexible), then you write a custom admin to manage all these "models".

Comment: yes, might be one solution. However, I want to use some other django features for the created applications, so there is probably no way out of the restart.

Comment: A possible usecase would be a pluggable app. Having "Django app plugins" that are downloaded from an "app store" and added to the system without restarting django, just reloading. How would one do that? Can I add models during runtime without an app? call_command('makemigrations") and call_command('migrate') are possible during runtime.